# Age check by birthdate to exact date, for jquery.validate

Tags: jquery, validation, date

I am using this script to verify if someone is over 16 when they enter a birthdate. The problem is, it only validates with current year accuracy, so if someone is turning 16 this year but still 15, it would still pass.

Can anyone tell me how I can validate to the day, the Date() javascript function doesn't have enough info online.

My code:

```
$.validator.addMethod("check_date_of_birth", function(value, element) {

    var dateOfBirth = $("#dob").val();
    var arr_dateText = dateOfBirth.split("/"); 
    day = arr_dateText[0];         
    month = arr_dateText[1]; 
    year = arr_dateText[2];

    var mydate = new Date();
    mydate.setFullYear(year, month-1, day);

    var currdate = new Date();

    var totalage = (currdate.getFullYear()) - (mydate.getFullYear());

    if (totalage < 16){           
        $.validator.messages.check_date_of_birth = "Sorry, only persons over the age of 16 can be covered";
        return false;
    }
    return true;        
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check whether the entered date > current date - 16 years like

```
$.validator.addMethod("check_date_of_birth", function (value, element) {
    if (this.optional(element)) {
        return true;
    }

    var dateOfBirth = value;
    var arr_dateText = dateOfBirth.split("/");
    day = arr_dateText[0];
    month = arr_dateText[1];
    year = arr_dateText[2];

    var mydate = new Date();
    mydate.setFullYear(year, month - 1, day);

    var maxDate = new Date();
    maxDate.setYear(maxDate.getYear() - 16);

    if (maxDate < mydate) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}, 'Sorry, only persons over the age of 16 can be covered');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6j4St/)

Comment: That works a treat, thanks heaps for your help Arun, much appreciated.

Answer (score -4):

change

```
maxDate.setYear(maxDate.getYear() - 16);
```

to

```
maxDate.setYear(maxDate.getFullYear() - 16);
```